# Ways of significantly speeding up Windows 10 loading on a modern low-performance PC?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, performance

I have a compact PC with the following specs:

- Intel [Z3736F](http://ark.intel.com/products/82115/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z3736F-2M-Cache-up-to-2_16-GHz) CPU (dual-core with HT);
- Integrated GPU
- 2GB DDR3 RAM
- 64 GB integrated solid-state memory (chips are soldered on the main board, not detachable).

This is my car PC, so I would like to get it working as soon as possible after turning the ignition on. What are my options for making it boot and login faster? Naturally, I have already trimmed my autorun list to bare minimum, and have disabled the anti-malware service (don't need it for this application, and even if I do manage to catch some nasty malware, I'll just wipe and restore from backup).

What else can I do?

Comment: Wonder if hibernate could be used.

Comment: @cloneman: it works, and I'd like to use it, but a) it's not *that* much faster (we do conserve time on logging in and loading the applications, but not so much on booting up), and b) I'm afraid it will kill the non-replaceable flash memory sooner than the rest of the device dies.

Comment: It will... Hibernate is really hard on solid state storage which is why most experts recommend disabling it with SSD drives. Standby would probably be significantly faster, otherwise I don't know how your going to speed up the boot significantly, you sound locked into the hardware in place and are using Win 10 which doesn't have a lot of customization options at boot. Perhaps a slim Linux distribution would boot significantly faster?

Comment: @acejavelin: thanks for the info, I will disable hibernation then. I know _modern_ desktop SSDs work for years and years with day-to-day use of hibernation, but my case is different.
I like your systems thinking, but unfortunately, I am locked into this hardware, and I absolutely need Windows. Let's face it, Linux software is mostly terrible. I use all 3 major desktop OSes extensively, and Windows beats them on usability by far.
I need to cut the power to the PC when it's off, so sleep is off the table as well. Otherwise it would be ideal.

Comment: capture a boot trace with the WPT: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE. For Windows 10 use the WPT from the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: have you made a boot trace?